# 4 men and 4 women are to be seated in a row. A man and a woman are dating and must be seated together. How many ways can this be done?

Tags: combinatorics

I was helping someone with their math homework and am having a lot of trouble with this question. I was wondering if anyone can please help me.

$\mathbf {Question:}$

4 men and 4 women are to be seated in a row. A man and a woman are dating and must be seated together. How many ways can this be done?

$\mathbf {Attempt at Solution}$

At first, I thought that there are 4*4 = 16 ways to make a couple. We count the couple as one object so there are now 7 objects to rearrange. So the answer seems to be 7!*16. But then this exceeds the number of ways to arrange the 4 men and 4 women (with no restrictions) which is 8!

The problem, I realize, is that we are double counting some of the couples. When we pick a couple and move them around (and count), then pick another couple and move them around (and count), it will happen that a couple we have counted before will be counted again.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you!

(PS: Sorry for my bad Latex-ing, it's been some time.)

Comment: Why are you making couples? Let it be $7! \times 2!$ ,$2!$ to arrange the dating couples.

Comment: First, does the order of couples matter? Is $(W_1 M_2, W_2 M_1)$ different from $(W_2 M_1, W_1 M_2)$?

Second, does the order within a couple matter? Is $W_1 M_2$ different from $M_2 W_1$?

Comment: I would interpret this question as the following: "*Alfred, Billy, Charles, Derek, Alice, Bess, Clarissa, and Darleene want to sit on a bench.  Alfred and Alice are dating and want to sit together.  In how many ways can this be done*" where here we already know who the dating couple is and this is not an unknown.  We don't care whether or not any other men or any other women are sitting next to or not next to one another apart from alice/alfred.  Under this interpretation, first pick whether the dating couple is sitting male-female or female-male, then arrange everyone else around them.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah, reading your interpretation and the then the question again, I believe your interpretation is correct.

Comment: This is of course a different question than "There are four men and four women who want to sit on a bench.  It is known that there is a couple who wish to sit next to one another but it is not known who the couple is.  In how many ways can they be seated (*where the seating is the only important factor, not who the couple is*)?"  to which the answer is $8!$ since any arrangement will include a male sitting next to a female and they could a priori be considered our couple.

Answer (score 2):

The couple must be placed togther, and there are 7 possible adjacent positions (1 and 2, 2 and 3, ..., 7 and 8), and once you select that, 2 ways to place the couple.  The other 6 people can be placed arbitrarily in the remaining 6 spots, and going through, the first can be placed 6 ways, the next 5, the next 4, etc.  Therefore, there are $$(7)(2)(6!)=(2)(7!)=10080$$
possible ways to place everybody.

Comment: in each $8!$, at least one man will be near to one woman, i.e., it will count as one arrangement they as couple. if so, all $8!$ can be counted. i think i did not understand this question.

Comment: It says there is 1 man and 1 woman who must be placed next to each other.  You are reading is at no man may be placed next to a woman.  I am not sure how you get to that interpretation.

Comment: I agree with this answer completely!